# Display data by date

Tags: sql-server, view

I have the following data:

```
NAME  DATE_TIME         VALUE
MARK  2017-02-22 10:30    23
MARK  2017-02-22 10:45    23
MARK  2017-02-21 10:45    10
MARK  2017-02-21 10:45    20
MARK  2017-02-20 10:45    20
MARK  2017-02-20 10:45    20
MARK  2017-02-19 10:45    15
MARK  2017-02-29 10:45    15
```

I want to have a view that shows the data like this, with a sum for each day in its own column:

```
NAME    22-02-2017 21-02-2017 20-02-2017 19-02-2017
----    ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
MARK    46         30         40         30
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example solution using dynamic [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).  I'm using a dynamic [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) because your dates will likely change over time.  (Note: *Your last example data row has an invalid date, so I corrected that in my example.*)

Assuming your data will not actually be static (as in your example data), then I think the dynamic [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) route is the correct solution.  However, it requires dynamic SQL which cannot be embedded in a view.

If a view is **NOT** an absolute requirement to solve this problem, then simply wrap the code in a stored procedure and execute it.

Take a look at [Questions About Pivoting Data in SQL Server You Were Too Shy to Ask](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/).  It has numerous [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) examples and goes into great detail.  Additional examples are [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164572/60085).

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @col AS NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @colCoalesceNull AS NVARCHAR(2000);

--Create sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SampleTable') IS NOT NULL drop Table #SampleTable
CREATE TABLE #SampleTable (
    Name VARCHAR(100)
    ,[DateTime] DATETIME
    ,DataValue INT
    );
insert into #SampleTable values 
    ('MARK','2017-02-22 10:30:00',23),
    ('MARK','2017-02-22 10:45:00',23),
    ('MARK','2017-02-21 10:45:00',10),
    ('MARK','2017-02-21 10:45:00',20),
    ('MARK','2017-02-20 10:45:00',20),
    ('MARK','2017-02-20 10:45:00',20),
    ('MARK','2017-02-19 10:45:00',15),
    ('MARK','2017-02-19 10:45:00',15);
;

--Create dynamic column names for PIVOT
SELECT @col = Coalesce(@col + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(PvtColumnName)
    ,@colCoalesceNull = Coalesce(@colCoalesceNull + ', ', '') + 'coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(PvtColumnName) + ',0) as ' + QUOTENAME(PvtColumnName)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateTime], 105) AS PvtColumnName
    FROM #SampleTable
    ) AS SampleTable
ORDER BY PvtColumnName DESC;

PRINT @col
PRINT @colcoalescenull

SET @sql = N'
with cte_SampleTable as
(
select 
Name
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateTime],105) 
        AS PvtColumnName
,DataValue
from #SampleTable
)
SELECT Name, ' + @colCoalesceNull + 'FROM cte_SampleTable
    PIVOT(Sum(DataValue)
    FOR PvtColumnName IN (' + @col + ')) AS PivotSampleTable';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```