# How to use an integer pivot in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I want to get multiples rows using a pivot:

```
FIXED  |    0    1    2    3    4
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
First  |    D1   C1   SP   A0   1B
```

I did it:

```
DECLARE @zero int = 0
DECLARE @one int = 1
DEClARE @two int = 2
DECLARE @three int = 3
DECLARe @four int = 4
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @zero) + '], [' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @one) + '], [' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @two) + '], [' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @three) + '], [' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @four) + ']'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM 
            (
                SELECT Principal.Fixed, Code.Alpha, Code.Position                
                FROM       Principal
                INNER JOIN Code ON Principal.Id = Code.PrincipalId
            ) SOURCE
            PIVOT 
            ( 
                MAX(SOURCE.Alpha) 
                FOR SOURCE.Position in ('+@col+')
            ) PIVOTABLE'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

And the output always is NULL:

```
FIXED  |    0    1    2    3    4
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
First  |   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can change  `FOR SOURCE.Position in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4])`

Comment: Check your select query and @col value. Is should work. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ad0067c2655c4626db05219ac081ca14

Comment: Thanks McNets. The problem is that the columns Position would be dynamic, like this: DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @zero+5) + ']

FOR SOURCE.Position in ([6],[1],[2],[3],[4])

Comment: Then is better to build a @col variable using values returned by your query.

Comment: This is an example of a dynamic PIVOT where the PIVOT columns are dynamically created - see if you can work you logic like this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165163/60085

Comment: wht is your real table like and sample data ?

Answer (score 2):

First I'd suggest to verify that you source query returns expected data:

```
SELECT     Principal.Fixed, Code.Alpha, Code.Position                
FROM       Principal
INNER JOIN Code ON Principal.Id;
```

I've set up a single test and it should works. (dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cf4e593716af4ae1b6d60828f8e1c2d3))

Second, you can build @col variable dynamically by using `Position` values returned by your main query, avoiding to build it using variables (@one, @two, ...)

```
DECLARE @col AS nvarchar(MAX),
        @cmd AS nvarchar(MAX);

SET @col = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Code.Position) 
                  FROM Principal
                  INNER JOIN Code ON Principal.Id = Code.PrincipalId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'')

SET @cmd =   'SELECT Fixed, ' + @col
           + ' FROM'  
           + ' (SELECT Principal.Fixed, Code.Alpha, Code.Position '                
           + '  FROM       Principal '
           + '  INNER JOIN Code ON Principal.Id = Code.PrincipalId) src'
           + ' PIVOT (MAX(Alpha) FOR Position IN (' + @col + ')) pvt';
```